# Particle physics, alpha decay, & momentum mathematics question

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, momentum, energy-conservation, nuclear-physics

Was reading through a physics textbook yesterday and came across a problem that I cant quite understand.

Most of the question is clear to me but for the very last equation ( kinetic energy of alpha particle = 58.5/58.5+1... ) I just can't quite understand where it comes from.

If someone could clarify where exactly this equation is derived (or if the publishers have made a mistake somewhere) I'd be incredibly thankful.

[image: The problem in question]

Answer (score 0):

When you throw a ball upwards, you and the Earth move "downwards".
The downward motion is not noticed because the mass of the ball is so much less than the mass of you an the Earth.
Also, effectively all of the work that you did in throwing the ball up becomes the kinetic energy of the ball and the kinetic energy of you and the Earth is negligible.

In the case of the nucleus and the alpha particle the disparity in mass is not nearly as great but because the nucleus is more massive than the alpha particle it takes much less of the energy produced by the decay than the alpha particle in the ratio $1:58.5$.
So all the energy produced is split $1$ part of the whole $(6.8\times 10^{-13}\rm J)$ to the nucleus and $58.5$ parts of the whole $(6.8\times 10^{-13}\rm J)$ to the alpha particle.
Thus the whole of the energy $(6.8\times 10^{-13}\rm J)$ corresponds to $1+ 58.5 = 59.5$ parts and the kinetic energy of the alpha particle is $\dfrac {58.5\,\rm parts}{1 \rm \,part +58.5\,\rm parts }\times 6.8\times 10^{-13} = 6.69\times 10^{-13}\rm J$.